# ckeditor can't access root directory IE9

Tags: php, internet-explorer, ckeditor, internet-explorer-9

I always have some problems with IE. The problem is that my website must work on every browser, including IE.

Everything works well for the ckeditor plugin named prgfilemanager (I can add pictures into my ckeditor textarea). Every browser are working except IE... I first succeed displaying ckeditor using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9.0">
```

Without that meta, the textarea isn't a ckeditor textarea.

My problem is that when I try to add pictures, nothing happens **ONLY IN IE**.
When I click to search pictures there is a popup with the interface with no root..
If i write `http://XXX/ckeditor/plugins/pgrfilemanager/PGRFileManager.php?type=Image&CKEditor=Description&XXX` everything works well on every browser except for IE..

I'm on IE9. How to make pgrfilemanager working on IE 9 ?

[image]

This is what IE gives me

Comment: So is this a question about CKEditor or about pgrfilemanager? Note that this isn't an official plugin. I would recommend changing the name of this question, as well as writing to that plugin's developers, because they may not be following StackOverflow.

Comment: What I want is to be able to insert pictures. All I know is that without pgrfilemanager I can't do that. What should I do ? Is there an official plugin that could allow me to insert pictures ? The problem is that I want to insert pictures using ckeditor, so my title is correct but I have to use pgrfilemanager. Thank you for answering though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to make it work. As I said, I used `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9.0">` in my files to make ckeditor working. What to do if you have the same problem that I HAD, in `ckeditor\plugins\pgrfilemanager`, open `PGRFileManager.php` and add the meta `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9.0">` on the `<head>`. Like

```
    <head>

      <!-- ADD THIS -->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9.0"> 

      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>PGRFileManager v2.1.0</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sunny2/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.treeview.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/PGRFileManager.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.treeview.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="SWFUpload v2.2.0.1 Core/swfupload.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.i18n.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
      <?php if (PGRFileManagerConfig::$ckEditorScriptPath):?>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PGRFileManagerConfig::$ckEditorScriptPath ?>"></script>
      <?php endif;?>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="lang/lang.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PGRUploader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PGRContextMenu.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PGRSelectable.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PGRFileManager.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PGRFileManagerContent.js"></script>

      </head>
```